# Super Easy Python Pandas - Merge two dataframes based on a column in a different dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two data frames:

df1:

```
    Calendar
0   Mauritius
1   MIL
2   EG
```

df2:

```
    Calendar    Country
0   0A          South   Australia
1   MEL         Australia - Victoria (Regional)
2   QLD         Queensland   Australia
3   Mauritius   Mauritius
4   7A          Australia - Tasmania
5   MIL         MILANO
6   NSET        TRADING   NSE Stock Exchange
7   AUF         Australian Fixed Income
8   EG          Eq Guinea
```

Expected output:

```
    Calendar    Country
0   Mauritius   Mauritius
1   MIL         MILANO
2   EG          Eq Guinea
```

When I try to merge using:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Calendar'])
```

I get an empty dataframe - how do I fix this?

Comment: The code looks ok with me. Could you share your data file to pastebin.com with proper expatiation date?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Everything needed for a [mre] should be cut & paste & runnable text in the post. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use change the order:-

```
df_merge=pd.merge(df2,df1,on='Calendar')
```

or you can do masking i.e

```
mask=df1['Calendar'].isin(df2['Calendar'])
df_merge=df2[mask]
```

Comment: thanks for this, but im still getting an empty dataframe when I use that

Comment: But I am not getting empty dataframe...I edited my answer added 2nd method for doing this....kindly have a look